# Spark Yarn process only running on single executor

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I have a cluster setup with one master and two slaves(managed via cloudera manager). Whenever I submit a spark code with master as yarn and in deploy mode as cluster, it does get executed correctly but when details are viewed in the Spark history server it shows that it gets executed in only one of the executors/workers.

But that is not the same executor, with every new/different run, the master seems to pick up one of the two workers.
What could be the issue?

I have tried giving --num-executors 2 as well but same result.

Comment: How many executors are free when job gets submitted ?

Comment: both the executors are free

Comment: @taransaini43 - note that "num hosts" != "num executors". what is the executors memory size? what is the host memory size? what happened when you execute " --num-executors 8"?

Comment: @Yaron i am sorry, by executors/hosts i meant worker nodes/data nodes.
Edited now.

Comment: by executors memory size, you mean worker nodes RAM? Both of them have 8GB ram but also have some distributed services on them. They have around 3-4 GB free RAM in both of them.
will let you know the host memory(i assume you mean master node by that) and the result of running  " --num-executors 8" tomorrow when i run the same. Thanks

Comment: Try also reducing the ram allocated for the executors by 1 GB. E.g from 5gb ram per executor to 4gb ram per executor.

Comment: @Yaron I tried this and now able to see 2 executors running. but how this happened ?

Comment: @GirishGupta - this question isn't active. it might be better if you'll ask a new question with the details of your own issue.